# How to use PHP to forward a file from one API to another via cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to write a PHP script that uses cURL to bridge two API's.

The first API generates a PDF and returns that data:
`$pdf = curl_exec($ch);`

The second API runs on Go using net/http which expects a file upload for further processing. I'm trying to send with:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['file' => $pdf]);`

Unfortunately this does not work with Go receiving err of `http.ErrMissingFile`.

I can make it work by storing the file to disk with `file_put_contents` and then use `new CURLFile` to load the file to send via cURL however I'm trying to avoid the unnecessary disk I/O.

I've tried several ways of manipulating the `$pdf` data however all have resulted in either `http.ErrMissingFile`, a 100 HTTP code response or an empty file upload.

Any idea in how to accomplish this?

Comment: In order for you to send binary data like that, you'll need to set the appropriate headers. Make sure you're setting your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` and ensuring that your content type is set to `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: You're not sending `$pdf` as a file upload, you're sending it as ordinary POST data. See the linked question for how you can turn a string into a file upload.

Comment: Thanks @maiorano84 and @Barmar

Simply setting the header was one my previous attempts and resulted in `http.ErrMissingFile`.

Solution was from the linked question in using `CURLStringFile` which worked perfectly even without setting any additional headers or mime type:

`$file  = new CURLStringFile($pdf, 'my_file.pdf');`